# How do I implement a play/pause button in my media player's notification bar for Android 3.0+?

Tags: android

I'm writing a streaming audio app, and I want to have a play/pause button in the notification bar, just like Google's music player's.
How do I do this?

Comment: You can use your custom layout for your notification.This link will help ful to you to make notification.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443946/music-player-control-in-notification

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding custom layout by using `RemoteViews`, refer to [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomNotification)