# Music player control in notification

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications, android-broadcast

how to set notification with play/pause, next and previous button in android.!

I am new with Android & also at stack overflow. So please bear with me.

[image]

I set notification when song is start to play like below :

`

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void setNotification(String songName){
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.god_img, null, System.currentTimeMillis());

    RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_mediacontroller);

    //the intent that is started when the notification is clicked (works)
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, AudioBookListActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.contentView = notificationView;
    notification.contentIntent = pendingNotificationIntent;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

    //this is the intent that is supposed to be called when the button is clicked
    Intent switchIntent = new Intent(this, AudioPlayerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, switchIntent, 0);

    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_play_pause_in_notification, pendingSwitchIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);        
}
```

`

I have create BroadcastReceiver like below :
 `

```
   private class AudioPlayerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        System.out.println("intent action = " + action);
        long id = intent.getLongExtra("id", -1);

        if(Constant.PLAY_ALBUM.equals(action)) {
            //playAlbum(id);
        } else if(Constant.QUEUE_ALBUM.equals(action)) {
            //queueAlbum(id);
        } else if(Constant.PLAY_TRACK.equals(action)) {
            //playTrack(id);
        } else if(Constant.QUEUE_TRACK.equals(action)) {
            //queueTrack(id);
        } else if(Constant.PLAY_PAUSE_TRACK.equals(action)) {
 //                playPauseTrack();
            System.out.println("press play");
        } else if(Constant.HIDE_PLAYER.equals(action)) {
 //                hideNotification();
            System.out.println("press next");
        }
        else {
        }
    }

}`
```

Now, I set custom notification successfully but how can i handle notification buttons and its events like play/pause, previous and next... etc. I also try using broadcast receiver but could not get any response.

Seeking solution and guidance from experts, please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Follw this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526228/how-to-put-media-controller-button-on-notification-bar/25379408#25379408

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to set a `custom intent action`, not the `AudioPlayerBroadcastReceiver` component class.

Create a Intent with custom action name like this

```
  Intent switchIntent = new Intent("com.example.app.ACTION_PLAY");
```

Then, register the `PendingIntent` `Broadcast` receiver

```
  PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, switchIntent, 0);
```

Then, set a `onClick` for the play control , do similar custom action for other controls if required.

```
  notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_play_pause_in_notification, pendingSwitchIntent);
```

Next,Register the custom action in `AudioPlayerBroadcastReceiver` like this

```
   <receiver android:name="com.example.app.AudioPlayerBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.app.ACTION_PLAY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Finally, when play is clicked on `Notification` `RemoteViews` layout, you will receive the `play action` by the `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class AudioPlayerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();

    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("com.example.app.ACTION_PLAY")){
        // do your stuff to play action;
    }
   }
}
```

EDIT: *how to set the intent filter for Broadcast receiver registered in code*

You can also set the `Custom  Action` through `Intent filter`  from code for the registered `Broadcast receiver`  like this

```
    // instance of custom broadcast receiver
    CustomReceiver broadcastReceiver = new CustomReceiver();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    // set the custom action
    intentFilter.addAction("com.example.app.ACTION_PLAY");
    // register the receiver
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: can you please help me My App is terminated somehow and I did not found how to restart app

Comment: and My app is termiated but notification is not termiated what to do in that case?

Comment: @PriyankaChauhan You can close notification in `ondestroy()` in case your activity got killed, notification will be closed too.

Comment: but onDestroy() is not calling if app is terminated by OS

Comment: how can I change views after executing pending intents like album art, title...?

Comment: How to change action icons programmatically ?