# Android Widget+Service

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service, android-broadcast

I have a music player which plays music using a service,all the broadcast receivers  within that service are defined inside the service and not externally.

I am totally new to widgets so i had been seeing a few tutorials.But they didn't help me much 
I am totally new to pending intents soo.I am so confused right now please help me out...
All i want to do is just trigger the broadcast inside the service using the button of the widget ...

Here is the copy pasted code which i had been trying to understand

```
 RemoteViews controlButtons = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget);

        Intent playIntent = new Intent(context, Music_service.class);



        PendingIntent playPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                context, REQUEST_CODE, playIntent, INTENT_FLAGS);

        controlButtons.setOnClickPendingIntent(
                R.id.bPlay, playPendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, controlButtons);
```

And here is my app 
:D
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `custom Intent Action` and set it as `PendingIntent` to the `widget` item ( button in your case)

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.app.ACTION_PLAY");
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context.getApplicationContext(), 100,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);
 remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bPlay, pendingIntent);
```

Then, change your manifest to handle the `Action` passed in `PendingIntent`

```
   <service android:name="com.example.app.services.CustomService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mediabook.app.ACTION_PLAY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Finally , when the play button is clicked , the `Service` will receive the `Action` and started. Check for the `Action` in `onStartCommand`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId) {

    if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("com.example.app.ACTION_PLAY")){
        // do your stuff here
    }
```

You can set similar custom `Actions` for all the required views in the `Widget`.

See the compile code here https://gist.github.com/androidbensin/4a9f044ac0b3110c049e

Hope your are good now. Let me know if any issues

Comment: please tell me if i can use broadcasts instead ??

Comment: can i  somehow trigger a broadcast inside the service

Comment: Yes sure you can use. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443946/music-player-control-in-notification/23445191#23445191

Comment: Yes. It doesn't matter widget or notification. Its about pending intent to remote views

Comment: hi,but this broadcast has been defined in it's own class right?I have this broadcast inside the service...when broadcasts are inside another class they are not registered in the manifest but they are registered like this

Comment: registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
    Player.BROADCAST_SEEKBAR));

thank you for your patience though

Comment: Move the broadcast as separate class. Sorry I have a meeting now. Try it and let me know , will answer after some time

Comment: well there are many broadcasts i really don't know how much code i will have to rewrite for it

Comment: seems like you are out of the meeting now :P :D

Comment: Was busy with work all day , sorry :) You can also set the `custom action` through `intent filter` from code. See my updated answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443946/music-player-control-in-notification/23445191#23445191

Comment: nevermind and thanx anyways i got it working ...i just was messing one thing up...everything was right with my code ... :)
I am accepting your answer