# How to show notification like music player on Lock screen in android oreo?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

Need help,
I want to show notification like a music player on the lock screen. I have tried this code to build notification and its working but in some of the device, notification is not showing in lock screen.

This code is working in a Motorola device but not working in the MI device.

Here is code:-

```
private fun showNotification() {
    val mNotificationManager = this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val contentView = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.layout_notification)
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTitleKey, "Test")
    contentView.setTextViewText(
        R.id.tvTitleText,
        "Hello Testing"
    )

    val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_01")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setShowWhen(true)
        .setChannelId("channel_01")
        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        .setContent(contentView)
        .setStyle(androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle())

    val notification = mBuilder.build()
    notification.flags = notification.flags or Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val name = getString(R.string.app_name)
        val mChannel = NotificationChannel("channel_01", name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        mChannel.lockscreenVisibility = NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
        mBuilder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
        mNotificationManager.notify(10, notification) //0 = ID of notification
    } else {
        mNotificationManager.notify(10, notification) //0 = ID of notification
    }
}
```

and here is layout file `layout_notification.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivQR"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivQR">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitleKey"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitleText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/23443946/5773037 :)

Comment: @NikunjParadva I tried bro. but no effect.

Comment: @NikunjParadva I am not developing a music player like the app. I have some other requirement. I just want to show image and text in the notification.

Comment: @NikunjParadva yes, I have checked that link and I have done all thing same as that to build notification and its working in Motorola like that. but not working in MI.

Comment: use on going notification
yourNotification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

Comment: @JainilPatel already added.